How to send ether to a smart contract constructor hard coded in the test case without using the Value field in the Remix IDE
I am trying to send 1 ether (hard coded) from a test case into the constructor of a contract. But everytime I run the test case I get an error message (error message image attached).

Below is the smart contract code:
pragma solidity ^0.8.27;

import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract A {
    address b;

    constructor(address _b) payable {
        b = _b;
        console.log(b);
        console.log(address(this).balance);
        console.log(msg.value);
        console.log(address(this).balance);
    }

    function payHalf() external {
        uint balance = address(this).balance;

        (bool success, ) = b.call{ value: balance/2 }("");
        require(success);
    } 
}

contract B {

}

Below is the Test case code:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

import "remix_tests.sol";
import "hardhat/console.sol"; 
import "../contracts/call_data.sol";

contract testSuite {
    A public a;
    B public b;

    /// 'beforeAll' runs before all other tests
    function beforeAll() public {
        //instantiate contracts
        b = new B();
        a = new A{ value: 1 ether }(address(b));
    }
}

I don't understand where I am making mistake. I don't want to use the Value field of Remix IDE. I am following a tutorial from a website and they are using VSCode to do the same. I am using Solidity version 0.8.27.

Do you want to use Remix IDE or Hardhat in VSCode?

I am happy to use hardhat in VScode. Can you please refer me to a resource that explains how to configure hardhat in VScode

As, it's mentioned in the 2nd point i.e., Custom Transaction Context of the Customization section of the Remix Documentation:

One can input custom values for msg.sender & msg.value of
transaction using NatSpec comments, like:
/// #sender: account-0 
/// #value: 10 
function checkSenderIs0AndValueis10 () public payable {
    Assert.equal(msg.sender, TestsAccounts.getAccount(0), "wrong sender in checkSenderIs0AndValueis10");
    Assert.equal(msg.value, 10, "wrong value in checkSenderIs0AndValueis10"); 
} 


Also, you need to make the beforeAll function of your testSuite contract as payable. So, your revised testSuite contract would be:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

import "remix_tests.sol";
import "hardhat/console.sol"; 
import "../contracts/call_data.sol";

contract testSuite {
    A public a;
    B public b;

    /// 'beforeAll' runs before all other tests
    /// #value: 1000000000000000000
    function beforeAll() public payable {
        //instantiate contracts
        b = new B();
        a = new A{ value: 1 ether }(address(b));
    }

    function testBalance() public {
        Assert.equal(address(a).balance, 1 ether, "Incorrect balance");
    }
}

Now, when you click on Run, the test will pass:


Hello Syed, thanks for your reply. I made the suggested changes in the code, however I am still getting the same error message in "Before All" function ("Transaction has been reverted by the EVM). Also testBalance() function also fails since the ether is not getting sent to the constructor.
Can you also explain the reason why do we have to add the "payable" keyword to beforeAll() & checkSender() functions. I get it that "payable" has to be added to the constructor of the contract so that value can be sent to the constructor from the sender, but why are we adding to the test case functions?

Adding the payable to the test case function is due to the same reason why we’ve added it to the constructor of contract A, i.e., to send value.

Have you added this line on top of the beforeAll function: /// #value: 1000000000000000000?

Thank you Syed. It compiled. Actually I overlooked and forgot to add "#" before value in the comment. But I still do not get why do we have to add "payable" to the test case function, 'cuz the Alchemy video course that I am following, they do not add "payable" to test case functions at all. Also is this NAT Spec comments only for Remix IDE? 'Cuz I don't see these type of comments anywhere in the Alchemy video course !!

Yes, that’s only for Remix IDE, and for Hardhat test, the test case function doesn’t have to be payable.

If you want to learn about Hardhat implementation in-depth, then you can watch this course of Patrick Collins: https://youtu.be/gyMwXuJrbJQ.

@Vermaji, kindly accept the answer if it helped you, so that it could potentially help others facing the similar problem. Thanks.

Oh yes definitely I have been able to resolve the problem. I just don't know how to accept the answer. Its my first time seeking help like this here in a very long time.

I guess I should either go with Remix IDE that has Hardhat configured or I should go with VSCode and Foundry. I tried configuring Hardhat with VSCode. All is done. I just can't figure out how to run tests on the command line

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
